# Cannot create font in andEngine

Tags: fonts, andengine

I am getting an error when trying to run this code:

```
FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
    final ITexture mainFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    font = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), mainFontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "font.ttf", 50, true, Color.WHITE, 2, Color.BLACK);
    font.load();
```

I am just creating a basic font for my application but for some reason I am running into an error message of the following:

```
05-12 15:34:04.048: E/AndroidRuntime(4540): java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
05-12 15:34:04.048: E/AndroidRuntime(4540):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:322)
05-12 15:34:04.048: E/AndroidRuntime(4540):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:296)
05-12 15:34:04.048: E/AndroidRuntime(4540):     at org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(FontFactory.java:172)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed my problem. It was a very simple mistake. I forgot to load font.ttf into my font folder within my assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. It was a very simple mistake. I forgot to load font.ttf into my font folder within my assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: another cause of this problem is what I had. The font file was called "font.TTF" not "font.ttf". Changing this fixed the error for me.